# Pegar a data com uma função

Tags: php, html

Preciso de ajuda com o seguinte:

**Metodo para pegar a data**

```php
function pegar_ano(){

   $year = date('Y');
   $ano = date('Y');
   //echo $year;
   $ano_anterior = $_POST['ano_anterior'];
   $ano_atual= $_POST['ano_atual'];
   $ano_posterior= $_POST['ano_posterior'];
   if($ano_anterior != " "){
   $year = $ano_anterior;
   }
   if($ano_posterior != " "){
   $year = $ano_posterior;
   }
   if($ano_atual != " "){
   $year = $ano_atual;
   }
   return $year;
   }
```

**Formulário no html**

```html
<form method="post" action="">
        <br><br>

        <button type="submit" class="button1" name="ano_anterior" value="<?php echo $year - 1; ?>" style="padding: 5px 20px;"> Ano Anterior </button>
        <button type="submit" class="button1" name="ano_atual" value="<?php echo date("Y") ; ?>" style="padding: 5px 20px;"> Ano Atual </button>
        <button type="submit" class="button1" name="ano_posterior" value="<?php echo $year + 1; ?>" style="padding: 5px 20px;"> Ano Posterior </button>

    </form>
```

**Dentro de outra function**

Colocaria o pegar_ano dentro de outra function para construir a data, para então fazer a consulta no sql

```php
 $data = pegar_ano().'-'.$mes.'-'.$a.$diacorrente;
```

Comment: Mas não entendi, qual é a dúvida?

Comment: A função nao esta pegando os POSTS para fazer as condições @MikeDoouglas

Answer (score 0):

Eu não estou certo quanto a sua pergunta. Mas, pelo que entendi você precisa de duas coisas:

1) Está faltando chamar a função em:
 `<?php echo $year; ?>`, deveria ficar `<?php echo pegar_ano();?>`

O que você está fazendo é chamar uma variavel ($year) não a função.

2) Para a função entender o $_POST é necessário você passar ele para função. Deste modo deveria por:

```
   function pegar_ano($post){

   $year = date('Y');
   $ano = date('Y');
   //echo $year;
   $ano_anterior = $post['ano_anterior'];
   $ano_atual= $post['ano_atual'];
   $ano_posterior= $post['ano_posterior'];
   if($ano_anterior != " "){
   $year = $ano_anterior;
   }
   if($ano_posterior != " "){
   $year = $ano_posterior;
   }
   if($ano_atual != " "){
   $year = $ano_atual;
   }
   return $year;
   }
```

Além disto você precisa passar essas informações para função, logo, `pegar_ano()` deveria receber os post ficando `pegar_ano($_POST)`;